# Le terme « confusant » est-il correct ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, étymologie, adjectifs

On entend parfois certaines personnes utiliser à l'oral le terme « confusant ». Je comprend bien sûr le sens mais j'ai un doute sur le fait qu'il soit correct.

Voici une phrase d'exemple :

> Ce que tu dis est confusant.

Je voudrais donc savoir si ce terme est correct en français. Et si ce n'est pas le cas :

1. Pourquoi certaines personnes l'emploient ? Quelle est son origine ?
2. Quel mot doit-on utiliser à la place ?

Comment: "confusant" n'est pas un mot "correct" en français c'est un anglicisme,le mot correspondant en français est "déroutant"

Comment: mais puisque c'est de plus en plus utilisé ça va finir par être un mot reconnu !

Comment: @jihed: Je ne l'ai jamais entendu de la part d'un natif.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: Je ne l'ai pas précisé dans la question mais j'ai bien entendu plusieurs ce terme de la part de natifs.

Comment: J'ai des amis québécois qui utilisent souvent le mot *confusant*. J'ai aussi des amis des bars que je recontrais losque j'étais en France, et ils le  même, mais d'une mannière plus réservée... moins que les québécois de toute façon :)

Comment: Personne ne parle de "confusionnant" que j'avais trouvé comme solution à ce cas particulier. "C'est confusionnant". Est-ce faux ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

En français standard on dit :

> Ce que tu dis prête à confusion.

L'origine de **confusant* est probablement le terme anglais *confusing*. Ce mot essaie de reproduire la structure du terme anglais alors que — manque de bol peut-être — le verbe **confuser* n'existe pas en français.

[*Confus*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/confus) est un adjectif qui vient de *confondre*, bien qu'il soit distinct de son participe passé [*confondu*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/confus), mais aucun de ces deux adjectifs n'a exactement le sens recherché. Ils décrivent l'état d'une chose plus que la difficulté de son appréhension.

*Prêter à confusion* est la locution qu'il est souhaitable de substituer à ce terme dans la majorité des cas. « Prêter à » signifie dans ce cas « être matière à ».

Comment: A noter que le mot français existe : *confondant*. Il n'est simplement plus très utilisé.

Comment: @RomainVALERI: *confondant* c'est émotionnel, tout comme certaines utilisations de *confondu* (en excuses ou en remerciements par exemple).

Comment: *confondant*, c'est la qualité d'une chose ou d'un acte qui provoque la confusion. Je n'ai pas compris ce qu'il y a de spécifiquement émotionnel. Une forte émotion peut en effet être *confondante*, mais ce n'est pas restrictif. Si ? Dans quelle définition ? [Celle du TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/confondant) me semble relativement large dans sa formulation

Comment: @Romain: je ne crois pas avoir vu la forme adjectivale utilisée pour autre chose que [le sens 6](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/confondre) — hmm, peut-être le 3.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Le participe présent adjectivé **confondant- ante** (1845) réalise le sens psychologique, avec une idée de « stupéfaction » plus active aujourd'hui que dans le verbe.  **Confondu** tiré du participe passé a perdu l'ancien sens fort de « fatigué, fourbu, détruit, ravagé » au profit de la valeur morale de « troublé, dévasté ». (copier  du *dictionnaire historique de la langue française*).

Comment: Il n'y a pas de meilleur moyen de décrire "une situation extrêmement confusante". "Extrêmement déroutante" n'aurait pas le même sens. La formulation "une situation qui prête extrêmement à confusion" serait lourde,  fausse et changerait même le sens.

Comment: Il y a un bon article de l'académie française à ce sujet qui répond entièrement à la question, http://www.academie-francaise.fr/confusant

Answer (score 8):

Le mot « *confusant* » n'est pas correct dans le sens où il n'est pas dans le dictionnaire. Cependant il n'est pas exclu qu'il s'y retrouve un jour si son utilisation va crescendo comme maintenant.

Comme le dit Stéphane Gimenez, le mot est une francisation de l'anglais « *confusing* ». Ce mot serait très employé dans les milieux de la communication comme la publicité. Stéphame parle de « *prêter à confusion* » pour les synonymes mais on peut également dire « ***porter*** à confusion ».

[Source](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/confusant)

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=porter+%C3%A0+confusion%2Cpr%C3%AAter+%C3%A0+confusion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cporter%20%C3%A0%20confusion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20%C3%A0%20confusion%3B%2Cc0), « porter à » c'est plutôt « induire ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : dans tous les cas, quelque chose  confusant ou qui prête / porte à confusion induira toujours les gens en erreur. ;-) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=porter+%C3%A0+confusion%2Cpr%C3%AAter+%C3%A0+confusion%2Cinduire+en+erreur&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cporter%20%C3%A0%20confusion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAter%20%C3%A0%20confusion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinduire%20en%20erreur%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Confusant est plus court et plus précis que "qui prête à confusion". La langue française évoluera, comme le reste.

Comment: Une correction : non, ce mot n’est pas seulement employé par « les milieux de la communication », on le retrouve plus généralement chez les nomades français vivant un pied dans le (petit) monde francophone et l’internet. Parce que l’internet est anglophone (le web français c’est plus intranet qu’internet). Aucun de ceux que je connais qui utilisent ce mot ne travaille dans la communication. Le métier de la com est juste un l’une des catégories parmi une multitude d’autres de bilingues, ou de « citoyens du monde ».

Comment: Confuses **me** n'est pas nécessairement cela.

Answer (score 7):

Le bon terme serait « [confondant](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/confondant_confondante/18131) » selon moi.

> Ce que tu dis est confondant.

Je suis francophone et je n'ai jamais entendu « confusant ». Par contre, j'ai souvent entendu le terme « confondant ». J'admets cependant, qu'il n'est pas beaucoup utilisé et dans la vie de tous les jours, car il y a une multitude de mots jargon pour le remplacer.

Exemple :

> Ce que tu dis est mélangeant.
>   Ce que tu dis est "fourrant".

Également, il n'est pas rare d'utiliser l'expression « porter à confusion » à la place.

> Ce que tu dis porte à confusion.

Par conséquent, je suppose que le terme confondant est méconnu.

Comment: *Confondant* n'a pas ce sens là. Voir mon autre commentaire et celui de Laure.

Answer (score 4):

non, le mot "confusant" en bon français n'existe pas. 
Cependant, un film culte "le dîner de cons" a mis ce terme en avant. 
Il est de plus en plus souvent utilisé dans le langage quotidien. 
Je remplacerai ce mot plutôt par l'expression "prêter à confusion" et non "porter à confusion"

Answer (score 2):

Les quelques fois où j'ai entendu le terme "confusant", le but était proprement humoristique.

Comme le dit @ping dans sa réponse, il est utilisé dans la pièce de théatre "Le Diner de Cons" adapté en film.

```
- C'était votre sœur.
- J'ai pas de sœur.
- Vous n'avez pas de sœur ? Je lui ai dit qui est à l'appareil, et elle m'a dit : « sa sœur ».
- Il a appelé Marlène !
- C'est pas votre sœur ?
- C'est son nom, Sasseur. Marlène Sasseur.
- J'pouvais pas savoir, moi. Elle me dit : « C'est Marlène Sasseur. » Avouez que c'est confusant.
```

A mettre, je pense, aussi en parallèle avec l'utilisation du néologisme en humour:

- "je vous presentes mes confuses" dans la pièces de théatre "Le Père Noël est une ordure"
- ou encore "c'est tout à fait bouleversif" dans le sketch "Cinéma Cinéma" des inconnus.

Answer (score 1):

Ce que tu dis est confusant. (commes les autres ont dit, c'est un anglicisme) pourrait être:

> Ce que tu dis m'embrouille (les idées).

[What you say is confusing (to me).]

> Vous l'embrouillez avec toutes vos remarques inutiles.

[You confuse him with your useless remarks.]